# 90s sci-fi book about humans on a alien reserve; one man escapes and returns to liberate his people

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

There is a sci-fi book I read in the 90's. It was old back then, so it's possibly been published earlier. It was in English and I suspect the author was either American or British.

From what I can remember of the story, humanity lives in a primitive state on a planet or large spaceship of alien design but they do not know this.

One man is kidnapped or manages to escape and finds out the truth, and then eventually returns back to his people to liberate them.

Comment: There is quite a lot of details. Though could go through [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can remember anything else?

Comment: OK cool, I cannot remember if it was part of an anthology or not, i cannot remember the cover, unfortunately no again to character names. What made it unique was that it seemed to imply that human was kept on a reserve, i keep thinking it was a huge ship in space for some reason, and their technology was kept at a stone age level in order to effectively control them.

Comment: Could it be Captive Universe by Harry Harrison ? Wikipedia has a plot summary here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe

Comment: Awesome!, I think that may be it! You are a legend! thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be *[Captive Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe)* by Harry Harrison?

> Chimal is a young Aztec tribesman living in an isolated valley which was sealed off from the rest of the world in ages past by a massive earthquake. Unlike the rest of his people, who are content with the way things are, he shows more interest in what lies outside the valley, and in asking questions that no one can answer. Indeed, he is altogether brighter; more intelligent than others, which often gets him into trouble and makes him seem "unusual" to his peers.

....

> After initial misunderstandings, Chimal meets the Master Observer, who hails him as the "First Arriver." He then learns the secret of the conspiracy that has been perpetrated against his people for centuries. The valley is merely the central cavity of a huge generation ship. The Aztecs are its passengers, tended by the ship's crew in the caverns, the Observers, on a centuries-long flight to Proxima Centauri, the nearest star to the Sun.
>
> Five hundred years ago, "The Great Designer," an Earth dictator, converted the asteroid Eros into a generation starship, spinning along its axis for gravity, and sent it on its journey. Because of the enormous distance involved and the relatively slow speed that it could attain, it would be the descendants of the original passengers who would arrive. To preserve order over the centuries, the passengers were split into two distinct groups, with each group genetically engineered for low intelligence in a different way and given the hierarchical, self-sufficient and order-loving Aztec culture. The Observers were similarly programmed and given a monastic culture to watch over the ship and the Aztecs. On Arrival Day, the two Aztec groups would be allowed to breed together, which would remove the artificial recessive traits and produce highly intelligent offspring able to colonize the new system.
>
> When he is shown the control center of the ship, however, Chimal realises there is a major problem. The Observers, too rigid in their thinking to understand the planetary observations, have overridden the flight plan and passed Proxima Centauri. On attempting to explain their mistake to them, he is denounced and hunted as a heretic. After pursuit through the ship, he initiates the Arrival program that breaks the barrier between the two Aztec communities and releases them from the valley section of the ship, and the Observers have no choice but to accept that Arrival Day has come. The book ends with the ship due to arrive at Centauri in decades, and Chimal anticipates the day that he will soon have equals to talk to.